# How fix Unity Xcode build error with yandex appmetria SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, yandex-metrika

During the build, when executing the following command:

```
rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --links --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" "/Users/admin/Desktop/IOSBUILD_1/Pods/YandexMobileMetrica/static/YandexMobileMetrica.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/*" "/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-btxrohwlgxvnfvdvyumfomktzqzv/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/YandexMobileMetrica/Static/Core"
```

an error appears:

Showing Recent Issues

> rsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/d9889869-120b-11ee-b796-7a03568b17ac/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/rsync.c(244) [sender=2.6.9]

that interrupts the build:

[image: Xcode Screenshot]

I downloaded the latest version of AppMetrica, assembled a build with other PlayerSettings parameters but this error remains.